# Query for multiple databases

Tags: sql-server-2000

Is there a way to write a single query so that if you are connected to database A it does one thing and if you are connected to database B it does another?

I am using SSMS 2008 to access SQL 2000 servers.

Comment: Sql Server 2000 is end of life. It no longer gets any patches... not even critical security patches. It's irresponsible to continue using it. Convincing management to upgrade is job #1.

Comment: I agree with this and we are in the process of upgrading but apparently that will take 6 months to complete across all 8 locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can define views on database A and on database B with the same name and columns, but different construction. Then your query is just to select from the view.

Comment: I sadly do not have access to add views or even temp tables as our DBA is afraid we will mess something up so am stuck with basically just using basic select statements. However both database A and database B have tables with the same name that have columns using the same name. Everything about them is the same in regards to structure. However I am wanting one query that pulls 6 columns of information from database A but only 5 columns of information from database B. I currently have it written as two separate queries one for each database's needs. I was just hoping I could condense it to one.

Comment: As I do not just have database A and B but 8 different databases that all want different columns pulled because they all analyze it differently. If this is not doable I understand this is more a hope then a request.